# Hide soft keyboard in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want to hide keyboard after clicking on `EditText` in android i tried below code but its not working.

```
 mPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    mPassword.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.showSoftInput(mPassword, InputMethodManager.RESULT_HIDDEN);
```

I have also given `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in activity manifest.
still i'm getting keyboard.Please tell me how can i hide soft keyboard??

Comment: why would you want to hide keyboard on edittext focus??

Comment: i want to use my own keyboard

Comment: Did you try my answer? Let me know if it helped you, please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to hide the soft keyboard

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mPassword.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Also,

If you want to hide when the activity starts, then edit your `manifest` file as

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

Comment: its not waorking.still after clicking on i'm getting keyboard. InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mPassword.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in your manifest file.

```
<activity
     android:name="YourActivity"
     android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
your_edittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (m != null) {
                    m.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
                    your_edittext.clearFocus();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution which will hide the keyboard from anywhere.

**1st** create in your activity of choice the listener for the state and the method that will do the closing (based on the open state).

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

  private boolean mKeyboardOpen = false;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // add "keyboard open listener"
    final View v = findViewById(R.id.pager);
    v.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int hRoot = v.getRootView().getHeight();
        int hView = v.getHeight();
        int heightDiff = hRoot - hView;
        // if more than 150 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
        mKeyboardOpen = heightDiff > 150;
        Log.d(TAG, "hRoot=" + hRoot + ", hView=" + hView + ", mKeyboardOpen=" + mKeyboardOpen);
      }
    });
  }


  public void closeSoftKeyboard() {
    if (mKeyboardOpen) {
      InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

**2nd** call `((MainActivity) getActivity()).closeSoftKeyboard();` from anywhere, e.g. your EditText's `OnClickListener()`.

Hint: I'm using the ViewPager root view (R.id.pager), but you should probably replace it with your view root id.